# User permission to see data in UI

Tags: java, database, hibernate, web, struts-1

We have very large application developed in Hibernate, Spring, Struts. Where all users can see each other data. There are users and usergroups. Now we want to add something like permission base access, e.g.:

```
Group1 - have access to data1 only
Group2 - have access to data2 only
```

Currently Group1 and Group2 can see each other's data.

This configuration can be change at any time like Group1 can see data of Group2 but Group2 cannot see data of Group1.

Following is what we thought:

- We have an existing module where we can give user permission for UI to view like restrict user to view particular page. Same way create rule for data.
- Assign rule to group or user in groups
- While fetching data from database, add WHERE clause to filter data.

But in this case we have to update so many SQL and we are trying to avoid it.

Can anybody suggest better option or suggestion?

Comment: Thanks for editing my question. I am new to this forum and was not aware of this formatting

Comment: On Same question above what will be better approach to filter data? On Database level or On JSP level? We are using SQL Server 2008 and struts.